# DatagridTemplateColumn Checkbox binding searching for property on viewmodel

Tags: wpf

In the following snippet, I have a binding that is searching for "Checked" on the viewmodel. But it is not in my ViewModel, it is on items in my DataGrid ItemsSource.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How do I make the binding use the items in ItemsSource?
I've searched high and low but can't find the problem...

**Edit**: DataGrid binding:

```
<DataGrid MaxHeight="250" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ..... etc.. above snippet here
        ...
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.....
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Question
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Answers to show if the Question is checked
    /// </summary>
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Question> _Questions;
    /// <summary>
    /// Questions for Definition of Done
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions
    {
        get
        {
            return _Questions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code for Viewmodel and Itemsouce binding.

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Question class and also in your DataTemplate give DataType="{x:Type local:Question}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding should work provided that the `Checked` property actually belongs to the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that you have set or bound the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to. Make sure that the name of the source property is "Checked" and that it has a public getter and setter.

If the Checked property belongs to the view model you could use a `RelativeSource` to bind to it:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.Checked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```